# How do I get Mathematica to return a function call unevaluated?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, expression-test

How do I get *Mathematica* to return a function call (conditionally) unevaluated? I expect this may use the slightly-mysterious `Hold` function.

As a toy example, suppose I want to define `AlgebraicQ` such that `AlgebraicQ[x]` returns `True` or `False` when `Element[x, Algebraics]` evaluates to `True` or `False`, but otherwise to returns `AlgebraicQ[x]`, just like the other predicate functions do. (I can't just ask if `Element[x, Algebraics] == True`, because this is itself unevaluated.)

Edit: The first thing that came to mind didn't work, as you can see:
[image: With the definition AlgebraicQ(a_) := Element(a, Algebraics), the function AlgebraicQ[Pi+E] returns Element(E+Pi, Algebraics) instead of the desired AlgebraicQ(Pi+E). Parens used in place of brackets because of platform limitations.]

I had tried this before posting, but on a recommendation I tried again with a fresh kernel (pictured above) with the same results. I also tried

```
AlgebraicQ[a_] := True /; Element[x, Algebraics]
AlgebraicQ[a_] := False /; ! Element[x, Algebraics]
```

based on an earlier suggestion but this seems not to work at all.

---

## Final working solution

based on Szabolcs' answer:

```
AlgebraicQ[a_] := With[{result = Element[a, Algebraics]},
  result /; MatchQ[result, True | False]]
```

which tests as expected:

> AlgebraicQ /@ {7, Pi, Pi + E}
>
> Out[2]= {True, False, AlgebraicQ[E + Pi]}

Comment: A proper predicate does not have the behavior you request, but returns `True` or `False` for any expression it is given.

Comment: @m_goldberg: The built-in `AlgebraicIntegerQ` has precisely the same behavior I'm describing. (How could a function possibly guarantee to return True or False when the answer is not even known to mathematicians?)

Comment: On OSX and v9 `AlgebraicsQ[x_Real] := Element[x, Algebraics]` works as you want.

Comment: @gpap: I can't imagine how, honestly. I mean, clearly that should work if I gave it a non-`Real`, but for a `Real` it should return `Element[x, Algebraics]` because that's what you're telling it to return. Very strange, I'd be interested to learn more about this case.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "as you want" I mean the [example you referred to](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SuFsW.jpg) (these are evaluated on a fresh kernel).

Comment: @gpap: What do you get for `AlgebraicQ /@ {7, Pi, Pi + E, I}`?

Comment: @Charles I deleted because of good answers you've received and to not confise future visitors. To be honest, I don't remember for sure, maybe it's me who forgot about the `Head`. But you seems to be sure, mistakes happen to me and I don't have any reason not to trust you so: I'm sorry, I should be more careful. :) You may want to delete old not relevant comments too.

Comment: @Charles sorry for the late response. [Neither of these get evaluated](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IyH95.png) (not the 7 either) to `True` or `False`. I don't understand why!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's how this can be done:

```
ClearAll[algebraicQ]
algebraicQ[x_] := Module[{result},
  result = Element[x, Algebraics]; 
  result /; MatchQ[result, True | False]]
```

The key to these types of problems is usually a special use of [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) inside `Block`/`Module`/`With` which allows sharing localized variables between the condition and the body of `Module`.

---

At this point I should note that the convention seems to be that any function that ends in `...Q` will *always* return either `True` or `False`.  Consider `EvenQ` vs `Positive`.  `EvenQ[x]`, with `x` undefined, gives `False`.  `Positive[x]` stays unevaluated.  I know of only a very few edge cases which don't follow this.  Naming this `algebraicQ` would violate that convention.

Comment: @Charles - How did you paste the image to SE?

Comment: @eldo See http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes

Comment: @eldo [Use the image button in the editor to upload it.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zij1pp183l8hwvq/Screenshot%202014-05-22%2012.46.41.png)

Comment: @belisarius - Thanks for pointing me to the SE-Uploader. This smart gadget should be mentioned somewhere in the SE-Help.

Comment: @Agreeing with the convention! I strongly hope that WRI sticks to this, minimizing headaches to sort out non-binary cases (`True`/`False`/unevaluated).

Answer (score 12):

Your earlier approach would have worked if you had actually tested the argument to the function (`a`) rather than the undefined symbol `x`...

```
AlgebraicQ[a_] := True /; Element[a, Algebraics]
AlgebraicQ[a_] := False /; ! Element[a, Algebraics]
AlgebraicQ /@ {7, Pi, Pi + E}

(* {True, False, AlgebraicQ[E + Pi]} *)
```

Comment: Hah! So at least I wasn't too far off the mark, just careless. Thanks for pointing this out!