# How to post message about invalid options and return unevaluated input?

Tags: programming, options

Consider this function.

```
Options[foo]={WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision};
SyntaxInformation[foo]={"ArgumentsPattern"->{_,OptionsPattern[]}};
foo[expr_,OptionsPattern[foo]]:=
  With[{prec=OptionValue@WorkingPrecision},
  If[TrueQ[0<prec<=Infinity],N[expr,prec],(* else *)Indeterminate]
];
```

In this case it does what I want.
[image: This works.]

But when given invalid options, foo should display a message and return what it was given. This is an example.
[image: Also want this.]

The Message above can be displayed using this:

```
Message[foo::optx,PlotRange,
  Inactive@foo[Sqrt[2],WorkingPrecision->20,PlotRange->All]
]
```

So how do I get my code to find the invalid option and return the expression it was given?

Comment: Have you seen `CheckArguments[]`? Its docs give a model for this sort of behavior under "Applications".

Comment: Another example (bit more complicated): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116633/4999

Comment: Potentially related, although not direct answers to your question: [How do I get Mathematica to return a function call unevaluated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48349/27951) and [How does MMA return an unevaluated expression on errors without going into an infinite loop?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/249608/27951).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CheckArguments`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CheckArguments.html) was mentioned in a comment, here is how you can modify your code to use it:

```
ClearAll @ foo;
Options[foo] = {WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision};
SyntaxInformation[foo] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}};
foo[expr_, o:OptionsPattern[]] /; CheckArguments[foo[expr, o], 1] := With[
    {prec = OptionValue @ WorkingPrecision},
    If[TrueQ[0 < prec <= Infinity],
        N[expr, prec],
        Indeterminate
    ]
];
```

The `pattern /; condition` on the left hand side of the `:=` is the key to returning unevaluated.

```
In[45]:= foo[Sqrt[2], WorkingPrecision -> 20]

Out[45]= 1.4142135623730950488

In[46]:= foo[Sqrt[2], WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotRange -> All]

During evaluation of In[46]:= foo::optx: Unknown option PlotRange in foo[Sqrt[2],WorkingPrecision->20,PlotRange->All].

Out[46]= foo[Sqrt[2], WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 1):

This does almost exactly what I asked for

```
Options[foo]={WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision};
SyntaxInformation[foo]={"ArgumentsPattern"->{_,OptionsPattern[]}};
foo[expr_,OptionsPattern[foo]]:=Module[{prec,validOptions},
  {prec,validOptions}=Check[{OptionValue[WorkingPrecision],True},{0,False},OptionValue::nodef];
  Which[
    (* Test 1 *)Infinity===prec,expr,
    (* Test 2 *)TrueQ[0<prec<=Infinity],N[expr,prec],
    (* Test 3 *)True,Indeterminate
  ]/;validOptions
];
```

Now for a screenshot showing how it works.

[image: screenshot]

The second example in the screenshot made the Message.
That is good enough, but I still wonder how I could get the names of the invalid options and use them in my Message.